# Can websites written in JavaScript make requests to SOAP API's?

Tags: javascript, api, soap

I have an API  written in SOAP 1.2 that I am trying to give to a developer whose website is written in Javascript and said they can not request the file because they do not know PHP. From my understanding the API  is already written and we just need to fill out the place holders (username,password). Since they do not know PHP, is it true that they can not use our API? Even though it's already written. Are JavaScript developers not able to request API's in SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem as long as [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is enabled ***or*** if you're referring to backend/nodejs JavaScript.

That said, many "JavaScript developers" will be unfamiliar or lack proficiency or "comfort" with the SOAP protocol. And, SOAP isn't early as magical to write JavaScript against in vim or notepadd++ as it is in C# with Visual Studio's autogenerated service wrappers (for example). It would be wise to write up some JavaScript examples, probably for both the front-end/browser and backend/nodejs.

Comment: There's a lot of NPM packages matching "soap".  OP could check them out.  (I have no idea)